# Run lm in data.table when response variable's name is customer ID

Tags: r, data.table, lm

Given the following example of the data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1000)
y.dt <- data.table("100197"=rnorm(6), "100198"=rnorm(6), "100199"=rnorm(6))
x.dt <- data.table("PC1" = rnorm(6), "PC2" = rnorm(6), "PC3" = rnorm(6))
```

The numbers in `y.dt` represent each customer id. I want to construct linear model for each customer.
(It would be great if I can do all at the same time)

For one customer, I have done by using:

```
Data <- cbind(y.dt[,names(y.dt)[1], with = F], x.dt)
Formula <- formula(paste(paste(names(y.dt)[1], "~"), paste(names(x.dt), collapse="+")))
lm(Formula, data = Data)
```

but it returns me an error saying that

```
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :
invalid term in model formula
```

**My questions are:**

1. How do I fix this error ?
2. How can I do the regression for all customers at the same time ?

Thank you

Comment: Your formula doesn't make sense. Did you even look at it? It returns `PC1 ~ 100197 + 100198 + 100199`. While the columns you have in `Data` are `100197, PC1, PC2, PC3`, so why are you surprised it returns an error?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Sorry. It was typo. It should be `100197 ~ PC1 + PC2 +PC3`

Comment: Your edit gives a new error now

Comment: @DavidArenburg Sorry again. It should be ok now

Comment: Did my answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the reason you are getting the error is because `y.dt` column names are numbers and it seems that `lm` doesn't understand that they are column names rather than just numbers when received from `formula`.

Gladly, this is not seem to be a problem if you will do that inside a `data.table` without using `formula`

If you'll run (with your original column names)

```
temp <- y.dt[, list(mylm = lapply(.SD, function(x) lm(x ~ .,  data = x.dt)))]
```

It will store all of your `lm` models in `temp` as `list`s.

So if you, for example, want the coefficients, you can do (each column of this output is a different client)

```
temp[, sapply(mylm, coef)]
#                   [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
# (Intercept) -0.38717712 -0.2199147 -0.2108260
# PC1         -0.09782968  0.2076343 -0.2295490
# PC2         -0.20720121 -0.1559755  0.3452985
# PC3         -0.14836259  0.6736415 -0.1785973
```

Which matches with your single attempt (I've changed the column names of `y.dt` here so it won't return an error)

```
Data <- cbind(y.dt[ , .SD, .SDcols=1L], x.dt)
Formula <- formula(paste(paste(names(y.dt)[1], "~"), paste(names(x.dt), collapse="+")))
lm(Formula, data = Data)

# Call:
# lm(formula = Formula, data = Data)
#
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)          PC1          PC2          PC3  
#    -0.38718     -0.09783     -0.20720     -0.14836
```

Comment: wrap any unusual names in backquotes and `lm` will be perfectly happy with them

Comment: @eddie, there is no need if you don't use `formula`. The `data.table` solution worked fine with the original names

Comment: I understand that - I'm just pointing out how you can use `formula` with unusual names.